# What does だなんて mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning, nuances, adjectives, i-adjectives

I came across with the next sentence:

```
「そんな呼び方をして、馴れ馴れしくはありませんか？」
「そんな、馴れ馴れしいだなんて」
```

Why is there a だ with a いadj? And what is the meaning or nuance of that だなんて?